# MailCore alternative for Android

Tags: java, android, android-library

Is there any library for Android like MailCore for Mac and iOS, which helps in working with e-mail protocols. Or is there any library or api that support for SMTP, IMAP, POP3, RFC822, MIME and rendering of HTML messages.

Answer (score 1):

The rendering of HTML is handled by `WebView`, or `TextView` for fairly limited HTML.

The rest would be handled by a third-party Java library, such as JavaMail.

Comment: Can I fetch gmail inbox messages using JavaMail?

Comment: @user2416657: AFAIK, Gmail supports IMAP and POP3, though a discussion of what protocols Gmail supports is off-topic for StackOverflow.